# How to write Superscript in ReactJS in navigation bar

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I am new to ReactJS and trying a simple portal page and stuck in a point. How to write a superscript in a navigation bar file.

I am reusing the existing project and need a way to write superscript to the text.

```
export const navHeader = { text: "Test Page", href: "/" };
```

How to get the result like Test Page ^ abc ( abc should be in power).

Comment: It's not clear what that code is. Does the text property accept HTML? How is it used?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the [`sup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) HTML Element, or wrap the text in another element and use the [`vertical-align: super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) rule

Using Native HTML Element

```html
<span>
  Test Page
  <sup>abc</sup>
</span>
```

Using CSS

```html
<span>
  Test Page
  <span style={{ verticalAlign: "super" }}>abc</sup>
</span>
```

Comment: This isn't going to work in the case presented. You can't pass HTML as the text string.

Comment: @a.mola Thank you for your answer! It worked for me.